# Require Android program to connect to a wifi printer and physically print contents

Tags: java, android, printing, wifi

I have an Android program that consumes an asp web service. Now I want my Android program to connect to a wifi printer and print the contents that it consumed from the web service. I have no idea where to start from and what resources to use.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i have used following code to print

```
import java.io.IOException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import com.iPrint.iObject;
import com.iPrint.iPaperType;
import com.iPrint.iPrint;
import com.iPrint.iPrinters;
import com.iPrint.iSettings;
import com.iPrint.ipConnection;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    iSettings set = new iSettings();
    set.SetPaperType(iPaperType.LETTER);
    set.PrinterType(iPrinters.HP);

    //Creating Connection object

    ipConnection wfc = new ipConnection();

    wfc.ipAddress("IP-Address");
    wfc.Port(port-number);
    try {
        wfc.Connect();
        Log.e("Connected",  wfc.isConnected()+"");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.e("In Error", "In Error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //Creating a Printing object
    iPrint p = new iPrint(getApplicationContext()); 
    p.Connection(wfc);
    p.Settings(set);
    if (wfc.isConnected())
    {
        p.Start();
        iObject ob = new iObject();
        ob.Text("Hello iPrint!");
        p.Add(ob);
        p.End(); 
        p.Print(); 
        ob = null;
    }
    else
    {
        Log.v("Error",wfc.ErrorMessage()+"");
       //showDialog(wfc.ErrorMessage(), AppContext);
    }
    print(getApplicationContext());
}
private void print(Context AppContext) 
{ 
//Creating Settings object
iSettings set = new iSettings();
set.SetPaperType(iPaperType.LETTER);
set.PrinterType(iPrinters.HP);

//Creating Connection object

ipConnection wfc = new ipConnection();
wfc.ipAddress("ip-address");
wfc.Port(port-number);
try {
    wfc.Connect();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    Log.e("In Error", "In Error");
    e.printStackTrace();
}

//Creating a Printing object
iPrint p = new iPrint(AppContext); 
p.Connection(wfc);
p.Settings(set);
if (wfc.isConnected())
{
    p.Start();
    iObject ob = new iObject();
    ob.Text("Hello iPrint!");
    p.Add(ob);
    p.End(); 
    p.Print(); 
    ob = null;
}
else
{
    Log.v("Error",wfc.ErrorMessage()+"");
}
 set = null;
 wfc = null;
 p = null; 
 }
}
```

add `iprint.jar` , i have done this way .

Comment: Hey did the words that you print, come in proper format or were they encoded in anyway?

Comment: Alright, cool. I shall do it and post if I encounter any problems. Thanks.

Comment: Hey one more thing, can you provide a link to iPrint.jar cant seem to find it. Thanks again

Comment: can you provide a link to iPrint.jar cant seem to find it. Thanks

Comment: um not yet bro.. says "V/Error(625): Transport endpoint is not connected" so trying to figure it out.. may be something to do with my network? is it? but anyways this is great help!

Comment: yeah there should not be any firewall

Comment: hey, the wfc.ipAddress("IP-Address"); refers to the local ip of the printer right? what about wfc.Port(port-number); is it any logical port number or?

Comment: i.e.  wfc.Port(2599); , wfc.ipAddress("192.xxx.xx.xx");

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22017/discussion-between-rstar-and-kasanova)

Comment: @Rstar what to give port no?

Comment: @J_K ask you admin to printer is connected with which PORT

Comment: @Rstar thanx, so admin give me port no and i print it..but if i have send image then how to send.

Comment: @Rstar iPrint SDK is payable as i found it from this http://iprintsdk.com/index.html link

Comment: @Rstar i having the jar and demo but asking as written there is payable or free because if it payable and we are using this way than may be in future they will take legal action so just asking for the confirmation

Comment: @Khan i found from internet so i don't have much idear and lots of person has used this jar not only by me.

Comment: @Rstar I can't able to connect to wifi printer,Also there were no exception. can you help me out

Answer (score 1):

I would start by looking at [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/package-summary.html) documentation. 
You then must understand (I assume you're working with a specific vendor, right?) the "printer side" protocol - 
 What exact data (and how) to send to it. 
I'm not sure if all wifi printers share the same API, it's up to you to check.

Comment: Oh thanks. but are there any code samples or any links as such that i can refer. Cause i want to know what libraries (eg: Socket etc.) should be used in android java programming to use in order to connect and physically print. Thanks