# getting an error "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can print only from an activity"?

Tags: java, android, android-print-manager

I am getting an error "`java.lang.IllegalStateException`: Can print only from an activity" while using an android 4.4 printing API.

is it work on all android above 4.4?

my code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Context cotext;
    WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        cotext = getApplicationContext();
    }

    public void printData(View view){
        doWebViewPrint();
    }

    private void doWebViewPrint() {
        // Create a WebView object specifically for printing
        WebView webView = new WebView(cotext);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                Log.i("TAG", "page finished loading " + url);
                createWebPrintJob(view);
                mWebView = null;
            }
        });

        // Generate an HTML document on the fly:
        String htmlDocument = "<html><body><h1>Test Content</h1><p>Testing, " +
                "testing, testing...</p></body></html>";
        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, htmlDocument, "text/HTML", "UTF-8", null);

        // Keep a reference to WebView object until you pass the PrintDocumentAdapter
        // to the PrintManager
        mWebView = webView;
    }

    private void createWebPrintJob(WebView webView) {

        // Get a PrintManager instance
        PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) cotext
                .getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);

        // Get a print adapter instance
        PrintDocumentAdapter printAdapter = webView.createPrintDocumentAdapter();

        // Create a print job with name and adapter instance
        String jobName = getString(R.string.app_name) + " Document";
        printManager.print(jobName, printAdapter,
                new PrintAttributes.Builder().build());

        // Save the job object for later status checking
        //mPrintJobs.add(printJob);
    }
}
```

please help me.

is there any example of android wifi printing?

Comment: May be this would help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14097990/require-android-program-to-connect-to-a-wifi-printer-and-physically-print-conten

Comment: Thank you @Dipalishah .  can i do with https://developer.android.com/training/printing/custom-docs.html

Answer (score 13):

I know this is late answer.

You have to use `YourCurrentActivity.this` instead of `getApplicationContext()`

Because  getApplicationContext() refers to an whole application `context` while `YourCurrentActivity.this` refers only current activity `context`.

Comment: I had used this instead of ActivityName.this and it still gave the same issue why? this also refers to the ActivityName.this right? then why was this issue faced for me?

Comment: @PrajwalW It depends from where you used this. If you are in the onClick event of any button and use this. The this refers to the button context.

Comment: I had used this inside of the function where we are calling PrintManager instance. So when I mention this in a function does that means it points to that functions context?

Comment: Probably Yes. May be it refers to function context.

Answer (score 13):

My application is using PDF printing using `PrintManager`. I got this issue after I implemented Multi-language support.

Android create a new `context` via `createConfigurationContext()`. This invalidates the reference being used by the `PrintManager` instance, causing the above `IllegalStateException`.

**Solution**

My solution is to store a reference of the original context passed by `attachBaseContext()`  a member of my activity. 
Then retrieve `PrintManager` instance by calling `getSystemService()` on the original `context` reference instead of the inactive `context` reference.

```
private Context originalContext;

@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    this.originalContext = newBase;

    super.attachBaseContext(LocaleHelper.onAttach(newBase,appLocale));
}

//  Starting printing (PDF generation):

PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) originalContext.getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);
```

Comment: Same here. I was giving an option to change language in my app. Then this problem occured. This answer solved my problem. Thanks! :)

Comment: Somebody should mark this one as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you're printing HTML content, this Android [training](https://developer.android.com/training/printing/html-docs.html) is faster and easier.

Now for the exception, I think you are getting this exception because of this line:

```
PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) cotext
            .getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);
```

The context you're using is an application context although you're in an activity and can/should just use the activity as a context. I'm not sure why you would need a separate `cotext` at all in this code.